# Are weakly étale ring homomorphisms of finite presentation étale?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, commutative-algebra

Following [Stacks, [`092A`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092A)], say a ring homomorphism $A \to B$ is **weakly étale** if both $A \to B$ and $B \otimes_A B \to B$ are flat.

**Question.** Are weakly étale ring homomorphisms of finite presentation étale?

According to Proposition 2.3.3 [here](http://arxiv.org/abs/1309.1198), the answer is yes. Unfortunately, the proof cites some results in a monograph on generalised commutative algebra, which seems to be overkill. I am looking for a more self-contained proof, or at least one that could reasonably be said to be purely commutative algebra (possibly including homological algebra).

Looking around in [Stacks], I found the following:

- By [`092M`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092M), weakly étale ring homomorphisms are formally unramified.
- By [`00UU`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00UU), a formally unramified ring homomorphism of finite presentation is unramified.
- By [`08WD`](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/08WD), a flat unramified ring homomorphism of finite presentation is étale.

This seems to be a complete proof that weakly étale ring homomorphisms of finite presentation are indeed étale. Did I miss anything? I'm surprised that this statement does not appear outright in [Stacks].

Comment: What about adding this to [Stacks]?

Comment: What's "generalised commutative algebra"?

Comment: @user26857: In the paper, Gabber-Ramero's "Almost ring theory" is cited.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually fairly easy. Indeed, if $f \colon A \to B$ is of finite presentation, then so is $B \otimes_A B \to B$ by [Tag 00F4 (4)](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00F4). Moreover, the latter is flat by assumption, and it is always a surjective ring map (i.e., closed immersion). Thus, by [Tag 0819](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0819), it is an open immersion onto a clopen subset.

Thus, the diagonal is an open immersion, which means that $f$ is unramified ([Tag 02GE](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GE)). Since it is also flat of finite presentation, this proves that $f$ is étale ([Tag 02GV](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02GV)). (In the Stacks project, *G-unramified* means unramified and locally of finite presentation.) $\square$

---

**Edit:** I just noticed that this is the same as the explanation that the Stacks project gives, spread over the various tags you linked. Thus, the answer is: yes, it works, and no, you didn't miss anything.

My guess is that the first tag you gave is Johan's idea of including the result in the Stacks project; the statement you are interested in follows immediately from it. Another contributing factor is the observation that the finitely presented case is *not* typically what one is interested in when studying the pro-étale topology.

This section seems to be mostly written to include Olivier's theorem, given in [Tag 092Z](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092Z). Certainly for that theorem, the étale case is not very interesting.

Answer (score 1):

This is kind of useless at this point, but since I was able to get a copy of one of Olivier's original articles on weakly étale/absolutely flat morphisms, I thought I'd share what I found.

The article

> Ferrand, Daniel. "Epimorphismes d'anneaux et algèbres séparables." *C. R. Acad. Sci. Paris Sér. A-B* **265** 1967 [A411](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k62358514/f137.item)–A414. [MR0244313 (39 #5628)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=244313)

is cited as to having introduced the notion, but I can't spot it explicitly. The article that I was referring to above is

> Olivier, Jean Pierre. "Montée des propriétés par morphismes absolument plats." *Comptes-Rendus des Journées d'Algèbre Pure et Appliquée (Univ. Sci. Tech. Languedoc, Montpellier, 1971),* pp. 86–109. Univ. Sci. Tech. Languedoc, Montpellier, 1971. [MR0342509 (49 #7255)](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=342509)

The definition there is:

**Definition.** Let $f\colon X \to Y$ be a morphism of schemes. We say $f$ is *diagonally flat* if $\Delta_f\colon X \to X \times_Y X$ is flat. We say $f$ is *absolutely flat* if $f$ is flat and diagonally flat.

Olivier mentions that it is easy to see that a diagonally flat morphism is locally of finite type if and only if it is *net,* that is, formally unramified and locally of finite type as in Raynaud's *[Anneaux locaux henséliens](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=277519),* using (a modification of) the proof in Ch. III, §4, Prop. 9 (which is basically [Stacks, Tag [092M](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/092M)]). Strengthening this to locally of finite presentation, and then using that flat and unramified morphisms are étale gives you your statement.

In later papers [Ferrand](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=318138) and [Olivier](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=716234) just state that the statement you want is true without much comment, as do recent papers like [Picavet's](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=3040918). What's also fun is that [Paxia](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=401751) cites course notes by S. Greco for this result.